# Proper karate ecma javascript version

Tags: ecmascript-6, karate

Is Karate framework supporting ECMA 6? I'm trying to create a karate-config.js using let and const and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Karate does not support ECMA 6 or [arrow functions](https://github.com/intuit/karate#javascript-functions). Hopefully in the future :)

EDIT: Currently Karate is based on the Nashorn JS engine, and when [Graal](https://medium.com/graalvm/oracle-graalvm-announces-support-for-nashorn-migration-c04810d75c1f) becomes stable, we will switch to it.

EDIT2: Karate 1.0 will be on Graal and will support EC6 ! https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide

Comment: Does that mean we might be able to do arrow functions in the future, within Karate?  I only ask this because of : https://github.com/graalvm/graaljs/blob/master/docs/user/JavaScriptCompatibility.md

Comment: @djangofan yes. https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/842#issuecomment-524653586